# How can I check for/use jQuery in closure loaded before jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have a js file that contains my closure, this file is loaded before jQuery, let's say it can't be moved. How can I pass in or check for jQuery with a view to use it in the closure?

This is what I've got so far:

```
(function MyClosure() {

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
            doJqueryStuff();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500);

    function doJqueryStuff() {
        // Some stuff with jQuery.
    }
})();
```

It actually works, but is there a "better" way? I always think I'm doing something wrong whenever I use `setInterval()` for things like this, also the fact I am losing time in that 500ms.

Comment: Is this happening because jQuery is being included before the closing body tag but this script is in the body elsewhere? Adding the defer attribute to this script's script element should fix it in browsers that support it, leaving the interval for browsers that don't.

Comment: @dm03514 They're using `setInterval`, so it checks every 500ms from the time it was called.

Comment: You can adapt this for your needs http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/05/07/load-jquery-dynamically.aspx

Comment: @Vladimirs That's basically the same thing as the OP's code, except they're using `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`

Comment: @Kevin B If I understand your question, both this script and jQuery are included normally in separate script tags in the document. It just so happens that when this closure is executed jQuery doesn't exist yet, and I'd like to use functions that utilise jQuery in the closure.

Comment: @igneosaur Then my suggestion would work for browsers that support it. Otherwise, there really isn't much else you can do than use a setInterval or ensure that the scripts are in the correct order.

Comment: @igneosaur how about loading jQuery in your own code? (in noConflict mode if needed). Then later jQuery will be cached for the second script load, so there should be minimal performance impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wait and attach your execution to the `window.onload` event, assuming jQuery is loaded once the window is loaded...

```
window.onload = function() {
    // do stuff with jQuery
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - while it does look hackish (at least to me and you) it isn't bad. Often times you need to wait until a complex object is initialized and you need to do the same thing. The best thing is to just ensure the order that your scripts load to solve any dependency issues - but as you requested let's assume the order can't be adjusted.

The only improvement I would suggest: adding an escape hatch to anonymous setInterval function. That way if jQuery never becomes available for some reason, the script can notify the user and stop checking.

```
var checkCount = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (checkCount++ > 20) {
        alert("jQuery could not be loaded - degrading user experience");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
        doJqueryStuff();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the onload event on the script tag. In this case, the doJqueryStuff should be a global function.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" onload='doJqueryStuff()'></script>
```